# Databricks Delta storage - Caching tables for performance

Tags: performance, apache-spark, caching, databricks

While investigating ways of trying to improve the performance of some queries I bumped into Delta storage Cache options, it has left me with several questions. (a little knowledge is dangerous)

`spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled", "true")`

- Does the code above affect just the notebook I'm in, or does it apply to the cluster.
- If it is the cluster does it resume after the cluster has been restarted?

`cache select * from tablename`

- Does the code above cache the table contents and can be benefitted from if I then do a select on 1 column and join to another table? or does the cache only operate if that exact command is issued again (select * from tablename)?

I've basically got 3 tables that will be used a lot for analysis and I wanted to improve performance. I've created them as Delta storage, partitioned on columns I think are likely to be most commonly used for filtering clauses (but not too high cardinality), and applied zorder on a column that matches all 3 tables and will be used in all joins between them. I'm now exploring caching options to see if I can improve performance even more.

Answer (score 2):

See https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/delta-cache.html

In short:

- It applies to your cluster and has nothing to do with your notebook.
- It does not support CSV, JSON, and ORC.
- Your choice of cluster config can affect the setup and operation. See URI.
- You can use Delta caching and Apache Spark caching at the *same* time. E.g. the Delta cache contains local copies of remote data. It can improve the performance of a wide range of queries, but cannot be used to store results of arbitrary subqueries. That is what Spark caching is for.

Comment: Thank you! clearly my search terms were not great because I never saw this page in my web-search. It answered all my questions :)

Comment: It is worth to add that the delta caching happens on the disk not the memory layer of the node. That´s why you should always opt for SSDs with high throughput.